# This project is out of date

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

When I want run my code (c++), I get 'This project is out of date.'
   Do you know, what I should be done for avoid from it?
   Thank's.

Comment: In visual studio 2015/17

Comment: Rebuild all, perhaps?..

Comment: Rebuild all, and check for files that have a corrupted date (in the future).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it happens due to modification time files and project files. clean your project. delete any auto generated files and re build the project. It will fix it.